# Automatically ajust QWidget height

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I would like to know how I can create a widget which will automatically fit the space when I will edit the height of the QDialog which contain this widget.

In the exemple bellow, the QPushButton will fit the width of the QDialog but not the height. However, if I create a QTextEdit instead of the QPushButton, the QTextEdit will fit perfectly the QDialog.

```
from PySide.QtGui  import *

class c (QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().setSpacing (0)
        self.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0); 

        btn = QPushButton()
        self.layout().addWidget(btn)

        self.exec_()

a = c()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The C++ documentation of the QBoxLayout Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) states for

```
QBoxLayout::addWidget(widget, stretch=0, alignment=0)
```

> If the stretch factor is 0 and nothing else in the QBoxLayout has a stretch factor greater than zero, the space is distributed according to the QWidget:sizePolicy() of each widget that's involved.

So having a look at the default [`Policy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) of a `QPushButton`

```
>>> btn = QPushButton()
>>> btn.sizePolicy().horizontalPolicy()
1
>>> btn.sizePolicy().verticalPolicy()
0
```

we'll find, that the vertical policy is fixed. Adding the button like

```
[...]

    btn = QPushButton()
    policy = btn.sizePolicy().horizontalPolicy()
    btn.setSizePolicy(policy, policy)
    self.layout().addWidget(btn)

[...]
```

will now automatically adjust the button with your dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the size policy to expand.
I don't know the syntax in python, but you can easily translate from C++.

```
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(this);
button->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```